# Calculus help on Area

Tags: calculus

I have tried this problem several times and cannot come up with the answer.
Let me know how to do it! :)

[image: Find area]

this is how i did it: [image]

Comment: Did you manage to sketch the region?

Comment: Can you share what you did on the several tries you mention? It'll help people give appropriate answers that don't just repeat what you already know.

Answer (score 2):

Just some hints:

- For $x_0=1$, $e^3=e^{3x_0}\neq e^{8x_0}=e^8$, so both functions don't intersect each other at this point.
- $e^8\gg e^3$.
- So look at the following plot done by Maple and decide:

[image]

Comment: Nice hints, Babak! +1